# link to anchor near bottom of page

Tags: html, browser

I'm doing some documentation where I make heavy use of anchors for linking between pages on a wiki.

see here:

http://code.google.com/p/xcmetadataservicestoolkit/wiki/ServicesExplained#Platform_Data_Structures

The feature that really makes this work well is when the browser shows the anchor at the absolute top of the pane.  When it gets confusing is when linking to an anchor shows the anchor half-way down the page since the page is scrolled down all the way

see here:

http://code.google.com/p/xcmetadataservicestoolkit/source/browse/trunk/mst-common/src/java/xc/mst/utils/Util.java#227

My solution in the wiki (first link) was to put a blank image at the bottom of the page simply to make the browser show the anchor right at the top.  Is there a better way to do this?  Is there a way to do it in the second link (in which I can't add a blank image)?

Comment: If you don't control the server (e.g. in the second example) I really don't see how you could change this behavior.  Images / extra `<br />`'s are probably the best solution on pages you can control.

Answer (score 9):

Putting a blank image at the bottom of your page is a bad idea, since it will expand your document to a unnecessary height.

You could throw in some javascript to apply an effect to the anchor you just travelled to, to highlight it wherever it is.

Answer (score 2):

Without altering the height of your document (i.e. adding extra padding at bottom), you'll always have this issue.

However, using bit of JS/jQuery, the **user experience** can be improved considerably:

On clicking a named anchor:

- Instead of jumping in a flash (broswer's default behavior), add a smooth scroll
- add an highlight to indicate current selection (this helps tremendously in 2nd case as the user can clearly see what is current)

Created a demo to illustrate the concepts: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/PYsyN/9/

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .current { font-weight: bold; }
</style>
```

**JS**

```
function smoothScroll(elemId) {
    // remove existing highlights
    $('.current').css({backgroundColor: "transparent"}).removeClass('current');

    var top = $(elemId).offset().top;

    // do a smooth scroll
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:top}, 500, function(){
        // add an highlight
        $(elemId).animate({backgroundColor: "#68BFEF" }, 500, function () {
            // keep tab of current so that style can be reset later
            $(elemId).addClass('current');
        });
    });

}

// when landing directly
if (document.location.hash) {
    smoothScroll(document.location.hash);
}
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
    // utilizing the fact that named anchor has a corresponding id element
    var elemId = $(this).attr('href');
    smoothScroll(elemId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a absolutre positioned pseudo-element with a great height to targeted block using just the following CSS (for the second link in your post:

```
#nums td:target a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 700px;
}
```

The height must be around the height of the viewport, so the best solution is to create these styles on the fly using js. But if you don't wan't to use js, just use `height: 1000px` or more — if you don't mind a gap at the bottom of course.

The best part: it's only CSS and there would be no gap when no anchors are targeted.

**Edit**: just a sneak peek into the future: if the [vw/vh](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) units would come to other browsers (now it's only in IE9), this could be awesomely done with just CSS using `height: 100vh` :)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use Javascript / jQuery to create a white `div` that has the necessary height needed to put your element at the top of the browser window, and you could even remove this upon scrolling away.

However I would highly recommend against doing so as this will expand your page where it isn't needed. It's a lot smarter to simply style the tag upon going there (through Javascript / jQuery) so it pops out to the viewer, for instance by setting the `font-weight` to bold or changing the `background-color`.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a combination of jQuery and PHP for this:

PHP(somewhere right after your `<body>` element):

```
<?php
    $anchor = explode('#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $anchor = $anchor[1];
    echo '<div id="selected-anchor" anchor="'.$anchor.'"></div>';
?>
```

And then the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#selected-anchor').css('background-color', '[Whatever highlight color you want]');
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.